# Check for message in notifications when app is opened

Tags: android, notifications

I'm doing a carpool app. In order to make people entering the ride, I make the driver send a notification to the riders when he/she wants to start the ride. After it, when the riders click at the notification, a boolean is changed at SharedPreferences and the ride is started. But, when the rider opens the app, without clicking any notification, it doesn't happen, what is reasonable since I haven't done anything to change it. That's why I want to check notifications everytime the user opens the app, but I have no clue how to do it.

My general listener ↓

```
public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
        try {
            sendNotification(json.getString("message").split("Message data payload: ")[0]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.handleIntent(intent);
    String msg = intent.getExtras().get("message").toString();
    System.out.println("Guia: " + msg);
    if (msg.contains("IniciarCaronaAgora")) {
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("emCarona", "true").apply();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("emCaronacid", msg.split("IniciarCaronaAgora cid:")[0]).apply();
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListaCaronasFragment.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If anyone receives a notification and the app isn't opened, the general listener will work and mine won't. Thats why i have a small part of the code at the main activity that, if has anything in the intent, will open an alert box. ↓

```
if (getIntent().getExtras()!= null){
        String message = getIntent().getExtras().get("message").toString();
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListaCaronasFragment.this).create();
        if (message.contains("IniciarCaronaAgora")) {
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("emCarona", "true").apply();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("emCaronacid", message.split("IniciarCaronaAgora cid:")[0]).apply();
        }
        ad.setTitle("Aviso");
        ad.setMessage(message);
        ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ad.show();
    }
```

Comment: you can't manage notification when application in backgtound ?

Comment: I use it's standard way. It normally shows the app icon and app name. I just control showing the message to the user. In other words, I don't control and, until now, I don't have reasons to.

Comment: As usual the answer is: you send a wrong notification type (asked many, many times something like *onMessageReceived is not called*)

Comment: Actually, even though you tried clarifying your answer, I don't think I got it because I don't repeatedly ask for the message received. I just want to check the notifications everytime the app is opened (check if any notification contains a specific message.

Answer (score 0):

Doing my researches, I concluded that few people tried to do what I wanted. It isn't about doing useless calls or sending the wrong type of notification, but that no one did it and published to the developers. So, instead of doing it through notifications (put someone in a ride), I decided to do that using my database, which guarantees persistance and reliability of data.